# Translate JPQL query to plain SQL

Tags: sql, logging, jpql, weblogic-10.x, ejb-2.x

I have a problem in my ejb java application .. and trying to solve it I stumble on this issue.
in my ejb class, I have a finder method

```
  /*   @ejb.finder signature="java.util.Collection findByAllMultiPlan(<list          
  of arguments>)" 
 *    
 * query="SELECT OBJECT(e)
 *                     FROM ElementTbl as e
 *     WHERE <LOTS OF STUFF>"
```

That method fails sometimes, not all the time.  (most of time when ran in a loop over a large data inputs)  It can fail on a 8th, 10th or 35th iteration, etc..
It fails with the "Finder" exception

> javax.ejb.EJBException: nested exception is: javax.ejb.FinderException: 
>       Exception in findByCriteria while preparing or executing query:  
>        statement: 'weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.PreparedStatement_com_inet_tds_r@bd44a1'
>         java.sql.SQLException: The transaction is no longer active - status:
>       'Rolling Back. [Reason=weblogic.transaction.internal.TimedOutException: 
>       Transaction timed out after 33 seconds
>
> BEA1-655E9CABEFC3D5D9F078]'. No further JDBC access is allowed within this 
>       transaction.java.sql.SQLException: The transaction is no longer active -
>       status: 'Rolling Back. 
>        [Reason=weblogic.transaction.internal.TimedOutException: Transaction timed 
>        out after 33 seconds BEA1-655E9CABEFC3D5D9F078]'. No further JDBC access is 
>        allowed within this transaction.

In a log files, I see query executed in weblogic jpql format

```
SELECT WL0.mreUidID, WL0.mreDtmCreated, WL0.mreCdeCustType, WL0.mreIn...
 .. many,many fields ...
FROM tblElement WL0 WHERE ( ( ( ( ( ( ( ( ( WL0.elVchID= ? ) AND (  
((((((((WL0.elVchAnotherId = ? ) .. and a lot of fields encoded with 
 "WL0.field =?"
```

There is NO output of values that are set in place of `?`
So, question is: Is it possible to translate that JPQL language into plain SQL so to run in query analyzer?
Again, query is very large to be parsing it every time I need to test a particular scenario... it will take me close to more than an hour to fill in everything..
There must be a java method or utility to get access to this from within my EJB class.
Please help !!!

Comment: It fails with "Finder" exception.  Some kind of time out exception.  I edited my original question to provide the exception output.  It looks better there, as it will get wrongly formatted here in a comment
Thanks